# Avada Page Template - How to set default to full width?

Tags: wordpress

I have a question about avada theme. When i create a page i have options to set page template in the right side. Default, Full width, etc... The default option is 3/4 layout in that.

The problem is when my plugins generate new pages it falls under default option where i wanted it to be full width one. I mean i have a ecommerce plugin installed and i create a page named SHOP where i could able to set full width. But when user click on a particular product it goes to detail page. That does not comes under wordpress PAGES option so i cant manually set width.

Is there any way to set default layout to full width in avada wordpress theme ?

Answer (score 1):

You're using a paid Wordpress theme; it's best to go to the site where you bought it for support. Few users here will have the theme or access to it. And your question has nothing to do with programming as per the Help Center: What topics can I ask about here?: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic